# Building Qt project with cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

Just installed **QT** and trying to build a **QT** project from inside the QTcreator using **Cmake** instead of **Qmake**.

I get the following error:

```
Starting to parse CMake project, using: "DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug", 
    "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=", 
    "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=",
    "DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=C:/Qt/5.13.1/msvc2015_64", 
    "DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=C:/Qt/5.13.1/msvc2015_64/bin/qmake.exe".
    The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/tany/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-pKrFgC/qtc-cmake-DqmsxZqd/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/tany/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-pKrFgC/qtc-cmake-DqmsxZqd/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Deprecation Warning:
  The 'cmake-server(7)' is deprecated.  Please port clients to use the
  'cmake-file-api(7)' instead.


CMake Project parsing failed.
```

Now if I use the **Cmake-GUI** instead, I can configure and generate the project files successfully, after supplying the environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

But I can't get this to work from inside the **QTcreator**.

Anyone has any experience with using **Cmake** with **QTcreator** then please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that your C++ compiler Visual Studio 2015 (64 bits) could not be located. Maybe when you run cmake-gui it finds another C++ compiler like mingw?
In Qtcreator's settings dialog you have a tab showing the detected compilers, and another one with the available kits.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that QtCreator is using a deprecated version of cmake. Update QtCreator to a new (unreleased, as writing this comment, version 4.10.0 is broken) or downgrade cmake to `choco.exe install cmake --version 3.11 --force` (a newer version might work).

Please also make sure to install `jom` (as this is the default for QtCreator/CMake on windows).

`choco.exe install jom` (how can I tell it to use make?)

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation warning is harmless. CMake deprecated the cmake-server and provides a new API for the same purpose now. Qt Creator will support that from 4.11.

The error tells you, that CMake is unable find the cl compiler. cl.exe comes with Visual Studio. Make sure you mark C++ there during the installation process. It is not installed by default anymore.

Alternatively install the MinGW tool chain from the Qt installer. In Qt context it is easier to use than the Visual Studio tool chain.